# Leetcode pronlem 46 passing parameter in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, parameter-passing

I am practicing Leetcode problem 46 and used a recursive way to find all permutation of an array (e.g.`[1,2,3]`).One can refer to the video [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KukNnoN-SoY) for details.

The code is as follows:

```
class Solution:
def permute(self,nums):
    answer=[]
    
    def recur(num,answer,s=[]):
        temp_s=[]
        for k in s:
            temp_s.append(k)      #perform deep copy
        if not num:
            answer.append(temp_s)

        else:
            for i in range(len(num)):
                other=[]
                for j in num:
                    other.append(j)
                s.append(num[i])
                other.pop(i)
                recur(other,answer,s)
                s.pop() 
    recur(nums,answer,s=[]) 
    return answer
```

My question is why do I need to deepcopy `s` in the first few lines, because when I didn't implement deep copy, the result is empty:

```
class Solution:
def permute(self,nums):
    answer=[]
    
    def recur(num,answer,s=[]):
        if not num:
            answer.append(s)

        else:
            for i in range(len(num)):
                other=[]
                for j in num:
                    other.append(j)
                s.append(num[i])
                other.pop(i)
                recur(other,answer,s)
                s.pop() 
    recur(nums,answer,s=[]) 
    return answer
```

> `[[], [], [], [], [], []]`

Comment: It usually pays to correctly tag the relevant programming language. It attracts the right experts.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to "find all permutation of an array".
Each permutation can only be stored as a modified copy of the array, otherwise the result can only be one of them, not all.
The recursive nature of the solutoon prevents the iterative approach, to modify the array, output it and then modify again.
So, if you never copy the initial array, achieving the goal would be impossible.

Comment: This is basically correct but might be unclear. The problem is that a single list is used throughout the recursive calls, so without a copy we append references of a single list to the result. As the call stack unwinds, the list is eventually popped down to nothing, destroying the data in the result list. Copying "freezes" the permuted list in the desired state when we reach the base case, avoiding aliasing and mutations (pops) and preserving the desired result.

Comment: This is correct, because every layer, the list is passed as reference.